# How can i call a variable from another method

Tags: java, methods, call

I need to know how to call a variable from one method to another
Can anyone help me?

```
public static void number(){
    number = 1;
}
public static void callNumber(){
    /*How can I call number to this method???
    */
}
```

Comment: You can [pass it as a parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) or [make it a class variable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, "call a variable from an other method" is not very explicit, since a variable in a method is either global (used in the method but naturally available in the entire program), or a local variable of the method.
And in this last situation it is impossible to get this value.

Then either you declare your variable externally and it is trivial, or you specifiy a type value to your method "number()":

```
public static int number() {
    int number = ...;
    return number;
}
```

and you call it:

```
public static void callNumber() {
    int numberReturned = number();
    // other things...
}
```

Note: your code `number = 1;` specifies that your variable is global...
The trick is to set "number" available either by the `return` of the method, or by specifying this variable global.

I don't know if I've answered your question, if not try to be more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Between static methods, variables can be shared by making them global, 
or by sending them as parameters(noas described by @Gaétan Séchaud).

However, if those two methods has a continuos connection between them, and they handle some variables needed to be shared, it smells like a class is needed.